# How to change format of a column of excel sheet in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, excel

I am creating an excel sheet dynamically and inserting values in to the same.But value in some cells are getting inserted in the wrong format.
Following is my excel sheet [image]
value in the selected cell should have been **0002-9343** but it is inserted as **Feb-43**.This due to some wrong format for that column(column-D) in the excel sheet.
I need to change the whole column-D (all cells comming under heading D "data2") to 'Text Format' before entering the data. 
Following is the code for creating the excel sheet and inserting data

```
excel = new Application();
            excel.Visible = false;
            wb = (_Workbook)(excel.Workbooks.Add(System.Reflection.Missing.Value));
            sheet = wb.Sheets.Add();
            sheet.Name = "TestSheet1";
            sheet.Cells[1, "A"].Value2 = "Id";
            sheet.Cells[1, "B"].Value2 = "Name";
            sheet.Cells[1, "C"].Value2 = "Data1";
            sheet.Cells[1, "D"].Value2 = "Data2";
            sheet.Cells[1, "E"].Value2 = "Data3";

            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                    id = i;
                    result = object;
                    data = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(result);

        name  = (data != null) ? data.name : string.Empty;
                    data1 = (data != null) ? data.data1 : string.Empty;
                    data2 = (data != null) ? data.data2 : string.Empty;
                    data3 = (data != null) ? data.data3 : string.Empty;

                    sheet.Cells[i + 2, "A"].Value2 = name;  
                    sheet.Cells[i + 2, "B"].Value2 = data1; 
                    sheet.Cells[i + 2, "C"].Value2 = data2; 
                    sheet.Cells[i + 2, "D"].Value2 = data3;
            }
            string ExcelPath = Some_path;
            wb.SaveAsExcelPath,XlFileFormat.xlWorkbookNormal, null, null, false, false, XlSaveAsAccessMode.xlShared, false, false, null, null, null);
            wb.Close(true);
            excel.Quit();
```

Now ,before the loop I need to change the format of cells under Column-D to Text Format.
How to do the same from code in c#?

Answer (score 8):

> Now ,before the loop I need to change the format of cells under Column-D to Text Format. How to do the same from code in c#?

To change the format of the entire column use this

```
// 4 is for Col D
sheet.Cells[1, 4].EntireColumn.NumberFormat = "@";
```

Remember to format Col D before you attempt writing to it. Using `.EntireColumn` will ensure that you will not have to change the format of the Excel Cells individually :)

Answer (score 2):

This is not the answer to your question, but I would recommend that you use the Open XML Api instead of using excel via Interop. 
There you can define the datatype for any cell you add to your spreadsheet.

```
Cell c = new Cell();
c.DataType = CellValues.InlineString;
```

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried using NumberFormat?

```
sheet.Cells[i + 2, "D"].NumberFormat = "@";    
sheet.Cells[i + 2, "A"].Value2 = name;  
sheet.Cells[i + 2, "B"].Value2 = data1; 
sheet.Cells[i + 2, "C"].Value2 = data2; 
sheet.Cells[i + 2, "D"].Value2 = data3;
```

Would recommend looking at easier libraries in the future. Interop approach is fully valid, but sometimes harder to get working like you want.