# How to format column of data in excel generated from MVC 3 application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, excel, asp.net-mvc-3

Basically my MVC 3 application generates an Excel file upon user request.
My problem, one of the columns contains data like the following "01/2015"... this represents a work-week of a year. This property is a string value in my application and displays perfectly on the screen within the application but once in Excel file, 01/2015 displays as Jan-2015. So workweeks 01 - 12 display as months Jan - Dec.
I cannot use a macro as this file will be generated new each time from the MVC 3 application. I being advised to create an exe file, using this exe file to locate the excel and run it allowing the exe to alter the data or column .
Unfortunately I have no idea how or where to start on that option ? Any ideas ?
The application is using a CreateCsvReport file to Create a memorystream that contains data (including headers) for a CSV report.

I tried to convert the "/" to "_" before the excel is created but to no effect!

```
 if (i.WorkWeek.Contains("/"))
                {
                    i.WorkWeek.Replace("/", "_");
                }
```

Comment: yeah, I thought that originally aswell, but all workweeks after 12 are formatted correctly, so how do you format a column where the majority of value are correct ? how would excel tell the difference ?

Comment: can you show code - think i might have a solution but want to see your implementation

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to change format of a column of excel sheet in c#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15805790/how-to-change-format-of-a-column-of-excel-sheet-in-c) - check out the top-voted answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/15806339/1666620

Comment: Again, this is going to format the entire column so will mess up all workweeks after 12.

Answer (score 0):

The following options seem to correctly display in my brief experiments.  Would these be acceptable?

1. Instead of `"01-2015","foo","bar"` you can prefix with =:  `="01-2015","foo","bar"` and it seems to correctly display
2. `"2015-01","foo","bar"` seems to display as-is (though the week number is after the year).